# foundation 4 reveal popup pass a variable

Tags: media-modal

I have an Archive and there is a reveal popup button for "see brief information" on each posts. it's from foundation 4.

When you click it shows the brief information of the post. so I need to pass $post_id to reveal popup.

How can I make it?

```
 <li><a href="#" class="tiny button secondary" data-reveal-id="detail-reveal">Click to see Brief infomation</a></li>
```

when you click it, it shows brief reveal popup.

```
 <div id="detail-reveal" class="small reveal-modal" data-reveal>

<?php if ($post_id) {?>
    <h2><?php _e('Information', 'kcm_fr'); ?></h2>
    <div class="row collapse">
    <?php // here I need to get the post id to use "get_post or wp-query..";    ?>
      Breif information is coming soon!
    </div><!-- row -->

<?php }else{ ?>
    There is no post id!
<?php } ?>

 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div><!-- reveal -->
```

How can I pass $post_id to reveal modal?

Thanks,

Comment: What is "reveal popup" and how exactly does one pass information to it? Please note that most people are unlikely to be acquainted with some arbitrary framework out there, provide more details on what you need to achieve and what _wordPress_ challenge you are facing with it.

Comment: [link] http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html [/link] this one I am talking about.